The quotient of a Dedekind domain by a prime power is isomorphic to the truncated polynomial ring
By $AKLB$ we mean a Dedekind domain $A$ with fraction field $K$; a finite separable extension $L/K$ of fields with $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. It follow that $B$ is a Dedekind domain with fraction field equal to $L$. Moreover, $B$ as $A$-module is finitely generated and projective.
Given $\mathfrak{q}\in\text{SpecM}(B)$, I want to prove that $B/\mathfrak{q}^n\cong \ell[x]/x^n$, where $\ell =B/\mathfrak{q}$ is the residue field.
My idea follows Sutherland's number theory notes, (Thm. $5.35$): let $\pi$ be a uniformizer for $B_\mathfrak{q}$ that can be forced to be in $\mathfrak{q}$, then the images of $(1,\pi^1,\ldots, \pi^{n-1})$ in $B/\mathfrak{q}^n$ are a $\ell$-basis for $B/\mathfrak{q}^n$.
The linear independence follow from the fact that each $\pi^i$'s has different valuations. To see that they generate $B/\mathfrak{q}^n$ let $\overline{x}\in B/\mathfrak{q}^n$, then it there exists $u\in (B_\mathfrak{q})^\times$ such that $x=u\pi^m$ where $m={v_\mathfrak{q}(x)}$. Since
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{q}^n=\{x\in L|v_\mathfrak{r}\geq 0\,\,\text{if}\,\,\mathfrak{r}\in\text{SpecM}(B)\setminus\mathfrak{q}\,\,\text{and}\,\,v_\mathfrak{q}\geq n\}=\{x\in B|v_\mathfrak{q}\geq n\},
\end{align}
we have that $\overline{x}=0$ if and only if $m\geq n$. Therefore if $\overline{x}\neq 0$ it has the form $u\pi^m+\mathfrak{q}^n$, moreover, because $u\in (B_\mathfrak{q})^\times$, we have $u=a/b$ with $a,b\in B\setminus \mathfrak{q}$. Hence, $\overline{x}=u\pi^m+\mathfrak{q}^n=\overline{u\pi^m}=\overline{u}\overline{\pi^m}$, where $\overline{u}\in \ell\setminus \{0\}$. This means that the images of $(1,\pi^1,\ldots, \pi^{n-1})$ generate $B/\mathfrak{q}^n$ over $\ell$. Finally
\begin{align}
B/\mathfrak{q}^n&\xrightarrow{\sim}\frac{\ell[x]}{x^n}\\
\pi^i&\to x^i
\end{align}
is the desired isomorphism.
I am not quite sure whether what I have written is correct or not. I have some doubts on the last three lines before the isomorphisms. Any corrections are welcome.
Thanks.

I also have this answer by KConrad, but it is not so immediate.

If we are in a mixed characteristic situation (meaning that $K$ has characteristic $0$ and $\ell$ has characteristic $p>0$), then this generally won't be true.
Consider for example $A=B=\Bbb Z$ and $K=L=\Bbb Q$ and take $\mathfrak{q}=(p)$ for any prime $p$. Then $B/\mathfrak{q}^n=\Bbb Z/(p^n)$, which has characteristic $p^n$, whereas $\ell[x]/(x^n)=\Bbb F_p[x]/(x^n)$ has characteristic $p$. Thus they can't be isomorphic if $n>1$. The mistake in your argument is assuming that $B/\mathfrak{q}^n$ is a vector space over $\ell$.
If you are in the equal characteristic situation, note that we may replace $B$ with its completion $\widehat{B}$, because completion doesn't change the residue field and $\widehat{B}/\widehat{\mathfrak{q}}^n \cong B/\mathfrak{q}^n$. But after completion, the Cohen structure theorem tells us that $\widehat{B} \cong \ell[[x]]$ and so the isomorphism you're after is the well-known isomorphism
$$\ell[[x]]/(x^n) \cong \ell[x]/(x^n)$$

I see that in general the action of $\ell$ on $B/\mathfrak{q}^n$, given by $\overline{u}\cdot\overline{x}=\overline{ux}$ is not well define since it can depend on the choices of the lifts. Then I don't understand the proof of the Thm. $5.35$ cited above. There we implicitly assume that $B/\mathfrak{q}^n$ is an $\ell$-vector space, but we don't say anything about the characteristic of $K$ and $\ell$. Am I missing something?

The proof you linked to is actually okay. The point is that the exponent here is crucial. Let's consider an example. Let $A=\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$ and $\mathfrak{q}=(\sqrt{2})$. Then $e=2$ and indeed it is true that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]/(\sqrt{2})^2\cong \Bbb F_2[x]/(x^2)$. But for example if $n=4$, then $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]/(\sqrt{2})^4$ has characteristic $4$, so it doesn't contain a copy of $\Bbb F_2$.

So in the setting of the theorem, if $n$ is the ramification index of $\mathfrak{q}$, my proof should be correct, provided that $B/\mathfrak{q}^n$ is a $\ell$-vector space. Would you mind expanding on why $B/\mathfrak{q}^n$ is a vector space over $\ell$ in this case?
